# 90s (?) movie with 3 story lines, one about a boy with powers, another about time travel to Nazi Germany, and lastly about a man in a retirement home

Tags: story-identification, movie, horror

An old movie with multiple story lines, possibly from the 90's.

1. A boy meets a teacher at a store or cafe and when leaving she accidentally hits his bicycle and take him to his home. Later she finds he has powers and he trapped a family in the house. She finally convinces him to let them go and she takes him with her.
2. A man gets in a fight at the bar with Germans and when he goes out of the bar he ends up in Nazi Germany time.
3. A man in a retirement home.

Comment: Hi there! :) there's already good info in there, but maybe you could take a look at [this guide on how to ask a good story-ID question](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/98028), see if that triggers any more memories you could [edit] in? For instance, did you watch it in English? Was it a translation? If you saw that on TV, would you know which channel it could have aired on? Stuff like that, to increase the chances of a successful ID. Cheers!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the [***Twilight Zone - The Movie***](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0086491/plotsummary?ref_=tt_stry_pl#synopsis) (1983)

> Four directors collaborated to remake four episodes of the popular television series 'The Twilight Zone' for this movie.
>
> In the first story (a vague remake of the Twilight Zone episode "A Quality of Mercy"), a loud-mouthed bigoted businessman with an intense hatred for Jews, blacks, and Asians, gets the tables turned on him when **he walks out a bar and is inexplicably transported back in time to being pursued by Nazis in 1940's France**, then as an African-American at a KKK rally in the 1950s Deep South, and as a Vietnamese in 1960s Vietnam.
>
> In the second story (a remake of 'Kick the Can'), an **old man arrives at a retirement home** and makes the wishes of the residents come true when he magically transforms them into youthful incarnations of their days gone by.
>
> In the third story (a remake of 'It's a Good Life'), a **young woman on the road gives a ride to a mysterious 10-year-old boy to his house and ends up trapped with other people in an alternate reality created by the boy's imagination**.
>
> The fourth story (a remake of 'Nightmare at 20,000 Feet) features a passenger on an airline whom sees, but cannot convince anyone, a mysterious creature on the outside wing of the airplane trying to sabotage the aircraft.
>
> <sup>[IMDB synopsis](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0086491/plotsummary?ref_=tt_stry_pl#synopsis)</sup>